# Can I change the step interval on a summation from 1 to something else?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I have seen integrations written as summations like this,

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\sum_{x=0}^x f(x)\,\delta x\tag{1}\label{one}$$

But I feel like that $\sum$ notation doesn't really explain what an integration does because the following equation is also true,

$$\lim_{\delta x\to0}\sum_{x=0}^x f(x)\,\delta x=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\biggl(f(0)\,\delta x+f(1)\,\delta x+f(2)\,\delta x+f(3)\,\delta x+\cdots+f(x)\,\delta x\biggr)$$

But an integration works like this,

$$\int f(x)\,dx=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\biggl(f(0\delta x)\,\delta x+f(1\,\delta x)\delta x+f(2\delta x)\,\delta x+f(3\delta x)\,\delta x+\cdots+f(x)\,\delta x\biggr)$$

So based on my understanding $\eqref{one}$ can't be true. If I can change the step interval from $1$ to $\delta x$ , everything is fine. Is there a conventional way to specify a different step or is there a way to write $\eqref{one}$ without specifying a different step? These notations confuse me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In which context have you seen the first definition? It seems completely wrong the way it is written, but maybe we can get a little background.

Comment: If you’ve seen it written that way, it is horrible abuse of notation. $\sum_{x=1}^x$ should never be used - it indicates two versions of $x.$ And neither is the $x$ in $f(x).$ Corrected, you can’t really really use this definition for an indefinite integral, only definite integrals.

Comment: Given any partition $P$ of the interval $[a,b],$ $a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots <x_n=b$ where $n$ varies, we define $$\delta(P)=\min_{i=1,\dots,n} x_{i}-x_{i-1}$$ Then if $f$ is nice $$\int_a^b   f(x)\,dx = \lim_{\delta(P)\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

Comment: Your version is more correct, but it assumes $\delta x$ divides evenly into $x.$ This is why we usually write it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n  f\left(\frac{xi}n\right)\frac xn$$ So $\delta x=\frac x n.$ But this only works if $f$ is defined near $0,$ and requires $f$ to be nice: continuous.  For example, $f(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$ is defined only for $x\geq 2,$ so you could not use this definition for that function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for detailed replies. Apologize for my delayed reply. I guess I have more than one misunderstanding about this. This is what I thought I saw, $$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx= \lim_{\delta x\to 0}\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)\,\delta x$$ Is that true? https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Engineering%20maths%20first%20aid%20kit/latexsource%20and%20diagrams/8_12.pdf

Comment: No, $\sum_{x=a}^b$ technically means $x$ takes integer values.  But you want $x$ to take the values $a+k\delta x.$  However, it is *sort of* right, if you take $\sum_a^b$ to mean something intuitively broader, rather than just integer sums. The problem is, notation means things. Given $\delta x,$ the real sum would be: $$\sum_{i=1}^{(b-a)/\delta x} f(a+i\delta x)\delta x$$ @Necor

Comment: Alternatively, you can define $$P(a,b,\delta x)=\{x\mid x =a+k\delta x, $k\geq 1\text{ and } x<b\}.$$ Then you can write your formula as: $$\sum_{x\in P(a,b,\delta x)} f(x)\delta x$$ This is closer to your notation $\sum_{x=a}^b,$ but the sum depends also on $\delta x,$ and your notation doesn't imply that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How does $\delta x$ change for the equation to depend on it? Does't $$\lim_{\delta x \to 0}$$ implies that $\delta x$ is a really small flexible number?

Comment: $\delta x$ affects the sum - which $x$ between $a$ and $b$ we choose to add together. @Necor I'm not sure what you mean by "the equation," but you are taking a limit of something that depends on $\delta,$ and one part of that dependency is which terms are in the sum.